# Understanding my router IPv6

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

I got my new Internet contract today. This is the first time I use this router and deal with IPv6. I want to host a local website on a home server. I went to the configuration page of the router and I found these two IPs:

Internet Status

IPv6 Address

`fe80::8af6:c7ff:fe13:36d5/64`

`2a03:8061:8300:0:25c5:7de4:7f1d:7170/128`

As I know I should create an AAAA record for my domain and put the IP of the router in it, and then forward whatever to my server.

However before doing any of that I did the following:

1- I put  `[fe80::8af6:c7ff:fe13:36d5]` in my browser, but I got the following message "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to [fe80::8af6:c7ff:fe13:36d5]"

2- I put `[2a03:8061:8300:0:25c5:7de4:7f1d:7170]` and got a similar message as the previous.

Shouldn't I get the admin page of the router when I put its address? So what's wrong?

Photo of router's admin page where I get the IPs:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Photo of forwarding an 8888 port to my laptop where I have [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) running on port 8888. I went to whatismyip.com and copied the ip and put in the browser: `theip:8888` but it didn't work.

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

The firewall in my mac is also turned off.

**EDIT 3**:

I went to google and wrote 'what is my ip' and I got an ipv6 that is different from the one I get from the router. So whatismyip.com gives and ipv4 and google gives and ipv6.

**EDIT 4**:

I went to a website that converts from ipv4 to ipv6 and entered the ip that I got from whatismyip.com and compared it to the one from google, but they are different.

**EDIT 5**:
The router is Technicolor TC7200.

**EDIT 6**:

A screenshot for the router firewall where I turned everything off, but still it doesn't work.

[image]

**EDIT 7**:

I spoke with a friend of me. He said that my ISP gives a shared IPv4 address so what I see on whatismyip.com is that shared IPv4 address, but my routers gets an IPv6 address and my local devices. He also mentioned that a friend of him was trying to do the same thing as me and he had to call the ISP asking for IPv4 or something, I really don't know what he asked the ISP for. But it was all related to the IPv4 vs. IPv6 issue. Now I'm so confused about what to do, or even WHERE to start to solve this problem!

**Edit 8**:

Here is the manual of my router: http://d.pr/f/hB9M

**Edit 9**:
I read the manual and I found that no all options that are mentioned in the manual are also present in the router config admin page. For example I don't have the DMZ Host option. Maybe the manual covers a lot of devices of the same brand or so.

Comment: You need to point your browser to your externally facing IP address. Visit http://www.whatismyip.com/ to find this. You will only get your router admin page if you have configured your router to be available outside the LAN. For a web server you do not need to do this.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams when I visit whatismyip.com I get an IPv4 IP and when I open that IP in the browser I get nothing.

Comment: You won't get anything since your router isn't configured to allow any traffic in. You can go ahead and set up your web server and port forward 80 onto the server. Then you can access it through your public facing IP or (if you set it up) your domain name.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I will check what you said, but please see the image

Comment: @MatthewWilliams it didn't work, I went to the router and did a port forwarding 8888 to my laptop (I have MAMP running), then I put theip:8888 but didn't work. That IP seems to be the public IP of the laptop.

Comment: Restart your router and don't put :8888. If you have configured HTTP to forward correctly the router will deal with it for you.Your laptop doesn't have a public IP it only has a LAN IP assigned by DHCP or custom.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams I remember a long time ago when I had a cisco router that I only copied the WAN ip from the router and then put it in the browser and then I got into the log-in page of the router. So in order for what I'm trying to do to work, is first to be able to get to the login page of the router with a public ip.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams please check the new edit and image to see if the forwarding is correct, should I do another forwarding or somethign?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring a network/ webpage from a user with a huge knowledge gap. This is only going to spin further out of control and should be in Chat or a forum.

Comment: @AlexTwain | At this stage your question has been answered. Your problem could be a misconfiguration with MAMP or a specific quirk with your brand of router. I suggest you start having a play around with your settings at all points - All I can tell you now is your public IPv4 address is what you want and port forwarding rules to your server.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams but shouldn't I get the login page of the router when I simply put the plain public ip? It's the interface/gate to anything!

Comment: @AlexTwain | Routers do not by default allow the admin page to be publicly facing. You can probably turn this on somewhere in your router configuration, but as I already said you don't (and really shouldn't) do this to set up a web server.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams please read edit 3

Comment: @MatthewWilliams, everything you have said applies to IPv4 *only*.  The question is specifically about IPv6 and with IPv6 there is no NAT and you don't need port forwarding.

Comment: @AlexTwain, what is the model of your router?

Comment: @heavyd The router is Technicolor TC7200.

Answer (score 3):

With IPv6, you typically don't need NAT and port forwarding because every machine on your network gets its own public IP address, this address is the address that Google is giving you when you Google "Whats my IP".

Your router should have an IPv6 firewall that is currently blocking incoming connections to the IPs on your LAN.  You will need to allow traffic destined for a specific IP (the IP of your machine with the webserver) on port 80 through the firewall in order to host your site.  Then you will need to setup the AAAA DNS record to point to your IPv6 IP.

Without knowing your router model its tough to say how to configure your firewall.

To test your server you would enter your server's IP address, which is the IP that Google was giving you.  Chrome accepts IPv6 addresses in the form of `http://[IPv6Address]`, so to reach Google you type `http://[2607:f8b0:400f:800::100e]`.  That should already work for you from inside your LAN.  You will need an IPv6 machine outside your network to test if your firewall is setup correctly.

Comment: The router is Technicolor TC7200.

Comment: I'm confused also about this bit of which one is router public ip address?! is it the one I get from Google or whatismyip.com or from the router admin page that showed in the screenshot?

Comment: The router admin page should show you both of the router's IPv4 addresses (LAN and WAN) and the router's IPv6 address (there is only once since there is no NAT with IPv6).  Google is showing your computer's IPv6 address.  whatismyip.com only shows your router's IPv4 WAN address.

Comment: I'm so worried about something. Today I spoke with my friend and he said that my ISP gives a shared IPv4, so what I see from whatismyip.com is the shared IPv4, but I get an IPv6 for the router/computer or whatever. He said that a friend was trying to do the same as me and he had to call the ISP asking them to do/enable something for that, which we don't know what was it. The whole problem was with the IPv4 vs IPv6 thing. But the problem he said that this was 1 year ago and maybe ISP won't offer that same thing now.

Comment: Can you guess what that might be? I'm so confused now and don't know what to do! Nothing is working with me!

Comment: Please see edit 6 because I attached a screenshot for the router's firewall

Comment: Here is the manual of my router because I really couldn't figure out how to enable only traffic to my machine ip, I can't find such an option in the router. http://d.pr/f/hB9M

Comment: Sadly, IPv6 support is pretty basic in many consumer routers.  Looking at the manual, I don't see anyway to open the IPv6 firewall via the GUI.

Comment: Not even "IPv6 Firewall: off"? or are we looking for a different thing? Have you seen the screenshot?

Comment: You can certainly turn the IPv6 firewall off, and it should probably work at that point, but you would leave all of your machines on your network exposed on the IPv6 Internet, which is not recommended.

Comment: If I turn the firewall off, how to test then my hosting server? I'm so confused about this point. What to type in the browser exactly? Can you explain this point in details please?

Comment: @AlexTwain, see my edits.

Comment: Oh great! I just copied the IPv6 from Google and put it like this: http:[IPv6 from Google]:serverPort and it worked. But now I'm wondering if this is a local IP or a public IP. i.e. I wonder that it worked only because I entered this IP from inside my LAN

Comment: It didn't work from outside :(. I asked a friend to open the exact URL but it didn't work for him, even tho I have the firewall off.

Comment: I also created an AAAA record for my domain and put the IPv6 address that I got from Google and it worked when I opened the domain from my computer. But then I asked a friend to try to open the domain but it didn't work. The firewall is still off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15727/discussion-between-heavyd-and-alex-twain).